# Prove that limit $\lim \limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{xyz\tan(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y)^2-z^2}$ doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the Limit doesn't exist

$\lim \limits_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{xyz\tan(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y)^2-z^2}$

I try to replace all of x, y, and z with what they are actually approaching. Please help me to prove that the Limit doesn't exist

Comment: I wrote a rather lengthy response to another, albeit simpler, question of yours.  Did that not give any insights?  If not, can you be more specific about what you have tried?

Comment: When trying to find a limit it means nothing when vars are replaced by what they approach and the result is $0/0$. After all in the one var case that is an "indeterminate form" of the sort that Lopital's rule is rigged for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint to make things a little easier: $$\frac{xyz\tan(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y)^2-z^2}=\frac{\tan(2x+y-z)}{2x+y-z}\cdot\frac{xyz(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y)^2-z^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

As suggested we have

$$\frac{\tan(2x+y-z)}{2x+y-z}\cdot\frac{xyz(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y)^2-z^2}$$

with $\frac{\tan(2x+y-z)}{2x+y-z}\to 1$ and

$$\frac{xyz(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y)^2-z^2}=\frac{xyz(2x+y-z)}{(2x+y-z)(2x+y+z)}=\frac{xyz}{2x+y+z}$$

which tends to zero for $(x,y,z)=(0,t,t)$ with $t \to 0$ but for $(x,y,z)=(t,-t,-t+t^3)$ we obtain

$$\frac{xyz}{2x+y+z}=\frac{t^3-t^5}{t^3}=1-t^2 \to 1$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find a path along which the limit is zero, they are all straight lines, except the ones for which the denominator is zero.

A path along which the limit is not zero is the curve $(-t+t^3,t+t^3,t+t^3)$ for which the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{4}(t^2-1)(t^2+1)^2=-\frac{1}{4}.
$$

Comment: We can simplify the path a little bit.

Comment: @user: yeah, I've seen your answer